# 2-space indentation not working in vim for global extern declarations

Tags: c, vim, indentation

I'm facing an issue with `vim` indentation, or maybe it could be the case that I'm missing some configuration to achieve desired result.

Below is the two spaces expected indentation:

[image: GoodImage]

But this is how it looks like when automatically I hit enter on first line, or I try to indent:

[image: BadImage]

Below are my `.vimrc` indentation related stuff:

```
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
set expandtab
```

Also, I tried to add below two lines one by one but didn't help:

```
set smartindent
set autoindent
```

I was exploring many options in vim `cinoptons` but nothing seems helping. I cannot say for sure what should be the correct indentation in this case. But I couldn't achieve what I want to. I have a in house developed IDE in my organization which does this job fine, but I didn't want to use that, because it's bulky and I really like vim+cscope+ctags+tmux combo when it comes to C coding/browsing.

Comment: "2-space indentation not working" is a tautology.

Comment: I don't think there's a setting to do what you want.  You would have type the two spaces.  Autoindent starts the next line at the same level as the previous line.

Comment: Have a read through of ':help C-indenting'. There are several options there that will achieve what you want.

Comment: I'll keep looking those many options in 'C-indenting' section. So far I find none. But till now I have seen many examples and it looks like what I'm trying to achieve is not very standard behaviour, may be that's why there is no way. But will see if I can achieve somehow.
Thanks for your comments.